# Como passar vetor como argumento no shell script?

Tags: json, script, shell-script

Gostaria de passar um vetor no maior estilo JSON como argumento para um script.

Exemplo :

```
#!/bin/bash

vetor[]=$1

echo ${vetor[*]}

i=0
        for nomes in ${vetor[*]}
        do
            i=$(($i+1))
            echo "Nome   $i é  $nomes"
        done
```

E gostaria de executar assim :

```
> bash MeuScript.sh [" Joao", "Jose", "Carlos"]
```

Existe algum modo de se fazer isso ? Pois tenho que passar essa estrutura como argumento e esse vetor tem que ser interpretado como um único argumento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não tem uma forma de passar arrays diretamente para o script. Uma forma de fazer isso é passando o array para uma variável antes, e passar a mesma para o script:

```
#!/bin/bash

vetor=("$@")

echo "${vetor[@]}"

i=0

for nomes in "${vetor[@]}"
do
    i=$(($i+1))
    echo "Nome $i é $nomes"
done
```

E a chamada ficaria assim:

```
$ nomes=('João' 'Maria' 'José')
$ bash MeuScript.sh "${nomes[@]}"
```